# Windows shows BSOD when trying to boot on dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, bsod, grub2, ubuntu-20.04

I am using a refurbished lenovo flex 14 machine I bought on ebay with a fresh windows 10 install. After it arrived I installed ubuntu 20.04 on the machine and used the configuration to install alongside windows. For one week I did not have any problems booting into ubuntu or windows, today I tried to boot into windows and got the BSOD, saying it found a critical problem with the computer and has to restart. After it restarts I get the option to restart again or use troubleshooting advanced options. Non of the troubleshooting advanced options works.
I don't know a lot about OS in general and don't want to damage the machine, so I haven't tried to make any changes using the windows prompt. I also don't know a lot about repairing tools, so I haven't tried using a bootable usb to fix the problem.
Ubuntu works perfectly fine, don't know what the problem may be.
On the BSOD the message shown is "CRITICAL PROCESS DIED". After restarting and before I access the advanced options for repair It shows the following message:\ Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC
Press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your PC or "Shut down" to turn off your PC.
Log File: C\WINDOWS\System\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt
I tried some tutorials to fix this kind of problem but can't seem to get it right. I am supposed to use the function "bootrec /fixmbr" which runs fine, and then run "bootrec /fixboot". This command doesn't run and returns "Access denied". That is everything I have done, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you able to boot into safe mode?

Comment: No, I couldn't access anything but the prompt. In the end I reinstalled windows from a usb drive, and don't have the issue anymore.